# of advantages of setting the reference variable of runner to the knockOut before the values to the runner variable are set

Tags: java

In the below example, the variable `runner` is being set to the `knockOut` object before the values for the variable `runner` are set.  What are the advantages over setting the variables to the object before setting any values to the following variable?  Any help is much appreciated.

Would there be any difference in CODE 1 and CODE 2?

### CODE 1

```
runner = new runner();
knockOut.setrunner(runner);
if(fpmlMap.get(ABCConstants.KNOCK_OUT_EVENT) != null 
    && fpmlMap.get(ABCConstants.KNOCK_OUT_EVENT).trim().length() > 0) {

    String  knockOutEvent = fpmlMap.get(ABCConstants.KNOCK_OUT_EVENT);
    runnerTypeEnum = null;
    runner.setrunnerType(runnerTypeEnum.fromValue(knockOutEvent));
}
```

### CODE 2

```
runner = new runner();
    if(fpmlMap.get(ABCConstants.KNOCK_OUT_EVENT) != null 
    && fpmlMap.get(ABCConstants.KNOCK_OUT_EVENT).trim().length() > 0) {

    String  knockOutEvent = fpmlMap.get(ABCConstants.KNOCK_OUT_EVENT);
    runnerTypeEnum = null;
    runner.setrunnerType(runnerTypeEnum.fromValue(knockOutEvent));
}
knockOut.setrunner(runner);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way, `knockOut` always has a reference to `runner`, regardless of the outcome of the following `if` block.

**Edit**

To respond to your edit: **there is no difference between the two examples**.  Both ways are valid and produce the same behavior.

(That's assuming that the code above is "normal" and does what a reasonable programmer would expect it to do.)

You might choose the first style to improve readability of the code, when taken in context.  However, the second style is more common in my experience.